# Add Handsontable to Colorbox

Tags: javascript, dom, colorbox, handsontable

I was wondering if anyone else has came across this. I have added handsontable to open in colorbox, but when I try to copy and paste into the handsontable nothing happens. I have looked at the DOM element and the event.target is set to div#colorbox and not the textarea.copyPaste which has been created by handsontable. So I can see why this is not working but does anyone have any idea on how to overwrite the event.target to point to the correct target.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem why this was not working is that as handsontable is rendering it is creating a new div for the copy and paste of these values. This div was being created outside of colorbox and was not accessible to handsontable, for now i have added 2 lines to handsontable.full.js to append this div into the colorbox div element and it is working.

This is a temporary fix for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I added the handsontable code inside the colorbox :

```
<div id="cboxLoadedContent">
    <!-- All colorbox code -->
    <div id="CopyPasteDiv" style="position: fixed; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;">
    <textarea class="copyPaste" style="width: 10000px; height: 10000px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0;"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```